# Cleaning tools of cured joint compount

Tags: drywall, cleaning

I had been using pre-mixed joint compound, but I ran out just before I was finished, and my neighbor (who had just re-done his basement) gave me some Sheetrock Easy Sand 90 Joint Compound, and his drill bit /paint stirrer so I could mix small batches.

Unfortunately, I missed cleaning the paint stirrer when doing my cleanup, and didn't remember it until a couple of hours later, when I was in class.  When I got home, I gave it a soak, and have scraped / scrubbed as much as I can off, but there's still quite a bit stuck on it in difficult to reach places.

Is there anything that might soften it? (eg, a strong base?  I have Barkeeper's Friend, lye water, and lye crystals), or do I need to stick with mechanical means?  (I have some brass brushes if I can remember where I put them)

Comment: Muriatic acid might do. It's what's used to dissolve mortar and concrete. You'll have to decide whether the cost of a new mixer is worth messing with dangerous chemicals, though.

Comment: Take it to diy car wash use pressure washer wand to blast it away

Comment: Yup, mechanical means. I think you ought to go buy your neighbor a new one or next time you need a loaner tool he might just say he does not have one to loan even though I (meant *he*, slip there) has a garage full.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it : you don't know my neighbor.  Making use of something that he has helps him justify being a packrat to his wife.  (but yeah, I need to replace it ... and he should be back in town tonight).

Comment: Pressure washer

Answer (score 1):

Soaking the stirrer in just plain water overnight should soften the compound. A scraper and wire brush will help get into the hard to reach areas. Most paint stirrers are usually less than $10. Is spending a hour or two trying to clean something so cheap worth the time?  I would just buy a new one for your friend and keep the old one.

Comment: Hot mud dosent break down like regular mud and water soaking usually won't work. I know my paint mixers cost in the mid 20$ range and they are worth cleaning.